# How to increase the number of the line within a comment that is constantly changing in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following line of code:

```
String myTeam = "TeamOne"; //at line 3
```

and I have another line of code:

```
//This line of code is referring to #3 line.
myTeam = "TeamTwo"; //at line 5
```

If write a new line of code before the declaration of the field, line 3 becomes line 4. How can I increase automatically `#3` from the comment to become `#4`?

Comment: It is not possible AFAIK. What is the use of that comment anyway? Anyone can simple see the line number at the left side. `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show line numbers`

Comment: If I write a comment and I say: `This line of code is referring to #3 line.
`, another programmer can write code before line #3 and line #3 will not be line #3 anymore.

Comment: Then don't comment `at line 3` use something else which will not change

Comment: I know this but there are many lines of code and can be confusing. Indicating the line code, cannot make any confusion. Btw, thanks for editing again. I'm only interested in Android Studio.

Comment: this type of comment makes the code harder to read. You don't need them, there are keybinds to find references

Comment: if you organize better that way go like this `//This line of code is referring to String myTeam = "TeamOne";`

`myTeam = "TeamTwo";`

Comment: like this you can after search for `String myTeam = "TeamOne";`

Comment: but again I DON'T RECOMMEND THIS TYPE OF PROGRAMMING

Comment: @Tiago_nes This was a simple example. What if the line is composed from 6-7 line. It will be a very long comment.

Comment: That is why i don't recommend this

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'll try to get used to without this.

Comment: You should not need that kind of precision in comments, that is why programmers choose intuitive names for classes attributes variables and methods.

Comment: @Tiago_nes I'll try to get used to this kind of programming. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In some IDE's if you select a variable, etc, the IDE itself will highlight every occurrences of that. Which is similar of what you want with those comments.

Comment: @Tiago_nes I'll try this way if is available in Android Studio. Thanks again!